# Removing panels (meta boxes) in the Block Editor

Tags: metabox, block-editor

When the **Block Editor** was added to WordPress, custom and core meta boxes became legacy, meaning, using the [remove_meta_box()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/) function won't work when removing meta boxes/panels displayed on the post editing screen.

So, how do we remove the `Excerpt` panel when we can't use `remove_meta_box()` anymore?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `remove_meta_box()` function will not work with the Block Editor, because these are now *Panels* and work differently. There is currently no documentation on how to disable Panels, but, *let's dance*.

We want to avoid *hiding* panels via CSS, and rely on the JS API.

We need to use the JS function `removeEditorPanel()` which will completely remove the panel with all its controls:

```
// remove excerpt panel
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'post-excerpt' );
```

Here is an (incomplete) list of panel IDs:

- `taxonomy-panel-category` - **Category** panel.
- `taxonomy-panel-CUSTOM-TAXONOMY-NAME` - **Custom taxonomy** panel. If your taxonomy is `topic`, then `taxonomy-panel-topic` works.
- `taxonomy-panel-post_tag` - **Tags** panel
- `featured-image` - **Featured image** panel.
- `post-link` - **Permalink** panel.
- `page-attributes` - **Page attributes** panel.
- `post-excerpt` - Post **excerpt** panel.
- `discussion-panel` - **Discussions** panel.
- `template` - **Template** panel added with WP 5.9.

### The full code

PHP (in your `functions.php` or custom plugin):

```
function cc_gutenberg_register_files() {
    // script file
    wp_register_script(
        'cc-block-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/block-script.js', // adjust the path to the JS file
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-edit-post' )
    );
    // register block editor script
    register_block_type( 'cc/ma-block-files', array(
        'editor_script' => 'cc-block-script'
    ) );

}
add_action( 'init', 'cc_gutenberg_register_files' );
```

The JS file (`block-script.js`):

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'taxonomy-panel-category' ) ; // category
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'taxonomy-panel-TAXONOMY-NAME' ) ; // custom taxonomy
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'taxonomy-panel-post_tag' ); // tags
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'featured-image' ); // featured image
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'post-link' ); // permalink
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'page-attributes' ); // page attributes
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'post-excerpt' ); // Excerpt
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'discussion-panel' ); // Discussion
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'template' ); // Template
```

### How about other panels?

If you know the ID of other panel than the ones listed above, please leave a comment.

On some panels, there is the alternative to to *hide* the panel via CSS. For example, to hide the `Revisions` panel, we can use:

```
.components-panel__body.edit-post-last-revision__panel {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Inspect the element of the panel to located the class name (`edit-post-last-revision__panel`). Note that some panels do not have unique class names.

So, register you block style:

```
wp_register_style(
    'cc-block-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/inc/block-style.css', // adjust file path
    array( 'wp-edit-blocks' )
);

register_block_type( 'cc/ma-block-files', array(
    'editor_style' => 'cc-block-style',
) );
```

And include your CSS code into the `block-style.css` file.

Comment: Also you can disable post status using `wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'post-status' ) ;`.

Comment: How do I find the ID of a custom panel. Is there a way to list the panels and their IDs in the Javascript console?

Comment: jQuery('.postbox')
in browser console should give you the meta box ids, and prepend id like this
```  wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'meta-box-mb-id' ); ```

Comment: FYI here’s how to remove the new “Template” meta box that was added in WP 5.9 (it’s no longer located within Page Attributes) `wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel('template');`

Comment: Very helpful, Thanks! Also take a look at Oceandigitals answer which shows how to do it without creating any js files.

Answer (score 7):

Addition to Christine Coopers answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/339437/31140

### How to remove non-core meta boxes

If you want to remove panels that were added by themes or plugins, proceed like this:

1. Find the **PANEL-ID** by inspecting the HTML code:
   Run `jQuery('.postbox')` in your browsers JS console.
   jQuery will find all custom meta boxes for you!
   You need to identify the correct box and copy the element ID.
   [image: Find the Panel-ID]
2. The internal panel ID of the meta box is **`meta-box-<PANEL-ID>`**

#### Example

```
// Remove the DIVI meta-box:
var boxId = 'et_settings_meta_box_gutenberg';
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'meta-box-' + boxId );

// Remove an ACF meta-box:
var boxId = 'acf-group_5d9b020a3db4e';
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'meta-box-' + boxId );
```

---

### How to remove core panels

See Christine Coopers answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/339437/31140

Answer (score 2):

To hide meta_box from *Block Editor* and display them **only** in classic editor add arg `__back_compat_meta_box` set to true when adding meta box

```
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box', 'My Meta Box', 'my_meta_box_callback',
    null, 'normal', 'high',
    array(
        '__back_compat_meta_box' => true,
    )
);
```

Comment: This wasn't what I was asking for specifically, but still good to know. ;)

Answer (score 2):

And this is how to get a list of core panel IDs:

```
wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).getPreferences().panels;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a faster solution, you can just add this functions in php.
This for example disables tags:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'webroom_add_css_js_to_admin');
function webroom_add_css_js_to_admin() {
 echo '<script>
 wp.domReady( () => {
  const { removeEditorPanel } = wp.data.dispatch("core/edit-post");
  // Remove featured image panel from sidebar.
  removeEditorPanel( "taxonomy-panel-post_tag" );
  } );
  </script>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why everyone wants to jump to JS and create a bunch of extra random files.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

```
function remove_post_support() {
    remove_post_type_support('post','excerpt');     
}
add_action('init','remove_post_support');
```

Comment: You are not hiding anything; you are removing the support altogether. So, if your theme uses excerpts on the front-end, it won't work.