# Function not working inside of a function in functions.php

Tags: functions, hooks, block-editor, permissions

I have the following function adapted from Christine's answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/339437/167562)  that works perfectly on its own to hide panels/metaboxes in the Gutenberg editor:

```
function irm_gutenberg_register_files() {
    wp_register_script(
        'cc-block-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/functions.js', // adjust the path to the JS file
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-edit-post')
    );

    // register block editor script
    register_block_type('cc/ma-block-files', array(
        'editor_script' => 'cc-block-script'
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'irm_gutenberg_register_files');
```

However, when I try to move this function to a larger function, it simply stops working:

```
function irm_lockdown_author_role() {

if (isset($userrole->roles[0])) {
    $current_role = $userrole->roles[0];
} else {
    $current_role = 'no_role';
}

if ('author' == $current_role) {

...

        function irm_gutenberg_register_files() {
            wp_register_script(
                'cc-block-script',
                get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/functions.js', // adjust the path to the JS file
                array('wp-blocks', 'wp-edit-post')
            );

            // register block editor script
            register_block_type('cc/ma-block-files', array(
                'editor_script' => 'cc-block-script'
            ));
        }
        add_action('init', 'irm_gutenberg_register_files');

    }
}

add_action('init', 'irm_lockdown_author_role');
```

Everything else in the larger function runs fine apart from this function. What's going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should never declare a named function inside another function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the function inside the function, and instead call the `wp_register_script` and `register_block_type` inside the large function.

Finally, remove the inner `add_action()` call, so you only have the ending one for the large function.

```
function irm_lockdown_author_role() {

if (isset($userrole->roles[0])) {
    $current_role = $userrole->roles[0];
} else {
    $current_role = 'no_role';
}

if ('author' == $current_role) {

        /* function irm_gutenberg_register_files() { */
            wp_register_script(
                'cc-block-script',
                get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/functions.js', // adjust the path to the JS file
                array('wp-blocks', 'wp-edit-post')
            );

            // register block editor script
            register_block_type('cc/ma-block-files', array(
                'editor_script' => 'cc-block-script'
            ));
        /* }
        add_action('init', 'irm_gutenberg_register_files'); */

    }
}

add_action('init', 'irm_lockdown_author_role');
```

Comment: Cheers, tested and working perfectly, but to be sure I understand the problem - what exactly are the reasons that this particular function wasn't working when other functions within the same function do?

Comment: Without testing it, you had an `add_action()` hook inside of another `add_action()` hook. These are set to run at certain times (in a particular order). Because you had them nested, this would have interrupted that flow. What this new change has done, and basically made that entire function run at once (in the order it appears).