# How do I disable the built-in editor and automatically configure the properties of new pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, custom-taxonomy, pages, editor

I use a Builder plugin on the site. Members are editors and can create their own page. I want to disable Gutenberg so that they can only edit pages with Buldir. I would also disable the properties of the page for them and I would enter it automatically. When I create a new page, I disable comments, the template is Blank Page, do not access the Custom fields. You can practically just add a featured image and title to your page, then click on the Bulder link and edit it. In the page menu, I disabled Editing and Quick Editing, and I also disabled editing the page URL. However, I can't specify the properties of the new page and I have no idea how to disable it without creating a new page with the builder.

I'm trying to influence the properties of the page with this code:

```php
function my_default_content( $post_content, $post ) {
    if( $post->post_type )
    switch( $post->post_type ) {
        case 'page':
            $post->comment_status = 'closed';
            $post_meta->_wp_page_tamplate = 'page-template-blank.php';
        break;
    }
    return $post_content;
}
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_default_content', 10, 2 );
```

I could update, but it's too late after editing the page - eg Blank Page template.
And even though I ban Gutenberg in vain, there is still an editing interface :(

```
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false' );
```

Could you help me?
Thanks

---

**EDIT:**

The WP engine changed completely in this respect around 2019. See [Removing panels (meta boxes) in the Block Editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339436/removing-panels-meta-boxes-in-the-block-editor/339437#339437) I have to approach the problem differently.

I was able to disable certain options using the code, but editors can overwrite the author of the page, which I can't disable for now. I also have problems with basic page settings - see e.g. Blank Page above.

In addition, I can't disable the Gutenberg textarea input field for editors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few plugins to disable Gutenberg Editor. Suppose you can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/). WordPress also provides an official plugin to disable Gutenberg and continue with Classic Editor. You can try out [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/)

Comment: I don't want an editor at all, just what I installed. And I don’t want the editors to poke at the properties of the page at all. Not when creating a new page or later.