# How to add editor panel with wp data dispatch?

Tags: block-editor

There is a [good question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339436/removing-panels-meta-boxes-in-the-block-editor) about how to remove panels from sidebar in Gutenberg.

My goal is to show Tag panel only for certain categories.
I want to add event listener for the categories checkbox and add editor panel.

Is there something like

`wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').addEditorPanel( 'taxonomy-panel-post_tag' );`

If you have other solution in your mind, please, suggest!

Answer (score 0):

After studying [documenation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-edit-post/) and [this documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301472/using-wp-data-subscribe-properly)

I came up with a solution.

We could use `wp.data.select('core/editor').getCurrentPost().categories` instead of `wp.data.select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('categories')`. Both should work.

```
/**
 * Show tags panel only for certain category using ID
 */
const { select, dispatch, subscribe } = wp.data;

window.onload = (() => {
    const categoryId = 9; // Category ID
    const toggleTagsPanel = () => dispatch('core/edit-post').toggleEditorPanelEnabled('taxonomy-panel-post_tag');
    subscribe(() => {
        const categories = select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('categories');
        const isTags = select('core/edit-post').isEditorPanelEnabled('taxonomy-panel-post_tag');
        if (categories && categories.indexOf(categoryId) != -1) {
            if (!isTags) {
                toggleTagsPanel();
            }
        } else if (isTags) {
            toggleTagsPanel();
        }
    })
});
```