# Metabox conditionals depending on post format and template in Gutenberg

Tags: javascript, jquery, block-editor, metabox

In the classic editor, I used jQuery to display metaboxes depending on the current post-format or page template selected. If a user selected a different format or template, they would toggle depending on what was selected. This was relatively straightforward within the classic editor and I used something like this:

```
$("select#page_template").on('change', function() {
    if( $(this).val() == 'template-1.php' || $(this).val() == 'template-2.php' ) {
        $("#my-metabox").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#my-metabox").fadeOut();
    }
})
```

Gutenberg breaks this code however. So how could one go about getting the same functionality (hiding/displaying metaboxes by post-format or page template) within the Gutenberg editor?

An approach I had tried earlier, doesn't work anymore and I'm curious about a better way of approaching this kind of functionality. Any replies or pointers would be very welcome.

```
$("#wpbody").on("change", ".editor-page-attributes__template select.components-select-control__input", function() {
    if( $(this).val() == 'template-1.php' || $(this).val() == 'template-2.php' ) {
    $("#my-metabox").removeClass('is-hidden');
} else {
    $("#my-metabox").addClass('is-hidden');
}
}); // Doesn't work anymore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to listen to Gutenberg events. Template change can be observed with something like this:

```
wp.data.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute('template'));
});
```

It will fire on many wp.data events, not only for template change. But you can add some checks and do your actions only when it's needed. Example:

```
const editor = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' );
let lastTemplate = null;
wp.data.subscribe(() => {
  if (lastTemplate != editor.getEditedPostAttribute( 'template' )) {
    lastTemplate = editor.getEditedPostAttribute( 'template' );
    console.log( 'current template:', editor.getEditedPostAttribute( 'template' ));
  }
});
```

You cant also check post format:

```
console.log( 'post format:', 
wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'format' ));
```

Adding and removing class `is-hidden` is not enough, you need to change react component state with this Gutenberg method:

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleEditorPanelEnabled( 'meta-box-' + 'my-metabox' );
```

Similar to suggestion from this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/349926/168823

Comment: Hey thanks, this was a really great reply! Do you know if there a way to check whether the editor has finished loading, rather than subscribing? Something akin to wp.domReady() but for the editor?

Comment: Hello, thanks for accepting my answer, honestly it was not easy to dig through all the editor source code and documentation to find out how it supposed to be used. If you want to check editor finished loading, maybe [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70530612/2234089) will do the job. If not, there could be some event, but I cannot find it fast enough, because I don't know gutenberg at all :) Tell me if it is not what you are looking for, I will check source code once more for you.